# Javascript for statement vs conditional and for statement performance

Tags: javascript

I have a question about what is better in javascript performance:

Having:

```
if (item.items.length > 0) {
    for (x = 0; x < item.items.length; x++) {

        var childElement = element.items[x];

        group.appendChild({
            classname: childElement.class_name,
            text: childElement.title,
            leaf: true
        });
    }
}
```

Or just directly

```
 for (x = 0; x < item.items.length; x++) {

        var childElement = element.items[x];

        group.appendChild({
            classname: childElement.class_name,
            text: childElement.title,
            leaf: true
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thats a good question :), I dont know how to test performance in javascript-

Comment: I think that `if` is redundent.

Comment: me also make sense that part.

Comment: the `if` is part of the `for` loop. `for(<initialize>; IF CONDITION; <do each loop>  ) {}` In other words: IF `item.items.length <= 0` the loop will never execute what is inside the »moustaches« (`{}`).

Comment: Second one(the direct one) is better because it does the same thing as the first one using less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: You do not need the `if` before the loop. The Definition of a `for` loop includes an `if` statement, to determine if the loop should loop on on not.

That would be an infnit loop:

```
for (;;;){}
```

this too:

```
for (var i = 0; true; i++) {}
```

in General:

```
for (<initialze>; <if statement>; <js do that each loop if you run>) {/*code*/}
```